# Tokens stuck in LP Pair contract due to a bug in token's contract

Tags: contract-development

So I hired a dev to deploy a token and it had taxes/fees on buys and sells. Due to a bug in the contract a part of those taxes/fees got stuck in the LP pair contract of the token. Is there any way to get them back? Here's the LP pair contract for reference. Its on CZ's chain

0x8804df350e17FE379803D245218Cdfe887Ae0825

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is unlikely. I would however see if you can contact dev resources or support for BSC. Maybe they will have better suggestions for you, if any.

Best of luck!